# How to show multiple markers from a list of names

Tags: javascript, google-maps, axios, geocode

javascript

```
       function loadMap(){
                  <!--set Map Options -->
                     var options = {
                    zoom: 9
                    };

          <!--New map-->
              var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options );

          <!--Get location to put marker-->
              var locations = document.querySelectorAll("[id='playgroundName']");

          var bounds= new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker();
          var infoWindowContent;

          <!-- Calculate Latitude and Longitude for location -->
          for (i=0; i!=locations.length; i++){
           var loc = locations[i].value;
              axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',{
                            params:{
                                    address:locations[i].value,
                                    key:'Your_Key'
                                    }
                            })
                            .then(function(response){
                            // Geometry
                            var lat = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                            var lng = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

                <!-- Add marker -->
                 marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position : {lat: lat, lng: lng},
                            map : map,
                            title: loc
                 });

                  <!-- Info window for marker -->
                  infoWindowContent= {content:'<h4> ' + marker[i].title +' </h4>'};
                  infoWindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow( infoWindowContent );
                  marker[i].addListener('click', function(){
                            infoWindow.open(map, marker[i]);
                  });

                  <!-- Form a boundary for map -->
                  bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                  bounds.extend(marker[i].getPosition());

                  <!-- Fit all markers on a map -->
                   map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
                   map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });

  }

                  map.setZoom(9);
}
```

`var locations = document.querySelectorAll("[id='playgroundName']");`
is passed from thymeleaf.
one of the locations.value = "Amberg Park" or "Barrett Brothers Park"
which is one of the names of the park I want to mark on maps. 
I need to create array of lat/lang for each name, and put markers with this array

This code displays markers on google map but every marker has same name, infowindow displays same(last) infowindowcontent for every marker. Fit bounds doesn't work as well. Reason must be cannot use for loop i variable inside callback function. I tried using different function to get array of location, that didn't work well either.

I also tried geocoder.geocode() as well to get lat and lang. I don't mind using axios/geocode() as long as I get lat/lang for individual marker.

Comment: What does the locations variable contain? Could you provide a sample (of the contents of that variable) and/or a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: As a matter of curiosity, why are you using `axios`?  The Google Maps Javscript API v3 Geocoder should work without an extra library.  Are you getting the correct results from those queries?  The examples you provided don't (necessarily) look like addresses, if they aren't working you may need to use the Places API.

Comment: Your issue with the name of the marker is the asynchronous nature of the calls to the geocoder.  You need to either use function closure on `loc` or deal with the asynchronous call back some other way.

Comment: I'm facing same issue with geocode(). It's has same issue. Someone asked me to use axios so above sample code has axios.

Comment: location is a NodeList(8) [input#playgroundName, input#playgroundName, input#playgroundName, input#playgroundName, input#playgroundName, input#playgroundName, input#playgroundName, input#playgroundName]

Comment: each item from NodeList is as follows, Only thing useful from it is location.value, So I mentioned only that above. Its too big.. cannot paste all in here

Comment: 0:input#playgroundName
assignedSlot: null
attributeStyleMap: StylePropertyMap {size: 0}
attributes: NamedNodeMap {0: id, 1: name, 2: value, 3: type, id: id, name: name, value: value, type: type, length: 4}
baseURI: "http://localhost:8080/results?searchBy=searchTerm&name=park"
childNodes: NodeList []
children: HTMLCollection []
classList: DOMTokenList [value: ""]
value: "Amberg Park"
valueAsDate: null
valueAsNumber: NaN
webkitEntries: []
webkitdirectory: false
width: 0
willValidate: false
__proto__: HTMLInputElement

Comment: Please [edit] your question to address comments.  It is really hard to read code in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a sample code for those who are struggling. I have 3 different arrays which I need to process something else for later, so pl don't judge the code.

Problem here was, JavaScript was asynchronously loading all the code without waiting for geocode to work. So putmarkers function was executing before getting any lat/lang. To make sure geocode gets lat/lang for all the locations I have used recordsLength variable.

```
var locationLat = new Array();
var locationLng = new Array();
var locationAddress = new Array();
var map;
var recordsLength;

function loadMap(){
  var options = {
    zoom: 1
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options );

  var locations = document.querySelectorAll("[id='playgroundName']");
  hasGeocoded= false;
  length = locations.length;

  for (i=0; i!=locations.length; i++){
    var address = locations[i].value;
    var geocoder =  new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        var add = results[0].formatted_address;
        createLatLngArray(lat,lng, add);
        }
    });
  }
}

function createLatLngArray(lat, lng, add){
    locationLat.push(lat);
    locationLng.push(lng);
    locationAddress.push(add);

    if(locationLat.length == recordsLength)
        {
        putMarkers();
        }

    }

function putMarkers(){
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locationLat.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(locationLat[i], locationLng[i]),
         map: map
    });
    marker.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
     return function() {
         infowindow.setContent(locationAddress[i]);
         infowindow.open(map, marker);
     }
    })(marker, i));
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```